# Error starting server with nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

So i am running an simple express web app, i install nodemon modules so i dont have to restart the server, but apparently there is an error

This is the error

```
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

[image]

I installed nodemon through npm and i installed it globally (into appdata/npm)
My server code is quite simple, here:

```
const EXPR = require('express');

// set up express app
const APP = EXPR();

// Handle get request
APP.get('/', function(req, res){
   console.log('GET request');
   res.send({"name":"Yoshi"});
});
// listen for request
APP.listen(process.env.port || 2000, function(){
   console.log("Now listening for request !");
);
```

Can anyone help me please, i really want this feature as it is very convenient for nodejs, thanks a lot !

Comment: your "node index" is working fine? and which OS you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows make sure to set

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;  /// this is c:\Windows\system32
```

in environment path.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked like a charm, btw i new to here so, if there is any problem with my english or my questiong asking style, please tell me, i will improve myself, again you guys rock !!!?!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  }
}
```

Then `npm start` should be enough to run your application. You should also consider putting `nodemon` as a dev dependency.

Comment: first i use your method, but there more error come in than usual, then i add the path of system32, it worked, btw thanks for the notice on the package.json !?!

Answer (score 0):

Open the windows powershell and add this line.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```